# SQL ORDER BY date problem

Tags: sql, date, sql-order-by

Can you please help me in solving this problem. I am trying to order the results of an SQL query by date, but I'm not getting the results I need.

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT date FROM tbemp ORDER BY date ASC
```

Results are:

```
01/02/2009
03/01/2009
04/06/2009
05/03/2009
06/12/2008
07/02/2009
```

Results should be:

```
06/12/2008
03/01/2009
01/02/2009
07/02/2009
```

I need to select the date in the format above.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's important when you post questions to provide specifics, like what database you're using and what datatype the DATE column is in your table. It makes it easier for people trying to help you; they don't have to guess.

Comment: While I know its not really essential to your answer I'd LOVE to hear a GOOD reason why that column isn't a datetime...

Comment: ORDER BY id (the auto increment value)

Answer (score 51):

It seems that your date column is not of type datetime but varchar. You have to convert it to datetime when sorting:

```
select date
from tbemp
order by convert(datetime, date, 103) ASC
```

`style 103 = dd/MM/yyyy (`[`msdn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)`)`

Comment: This won't sort correctly if the current language and date format settings cause interpret aa/bb/cccc as month/day/year, as is the case for most US installations of SQL Server. (I'm assuming from the use of CONVERT that this is T-SQL, so you can specify style 103 as the optional third parameter to CONVERT and override any language or dateformat context.)

Comment: I would love to know how anyone could figure out that these dates were not of `datetime` but `varchar` from the information provided.  Why should there be fewer results than initially shown, just by changing the field type?  Shouldn't there need to be a `WHERE` clause to reduce the answers returned, if it is giving all of the results, when it should be giving only some of them?

Answer (score 19):

It sounds to me like your column isn't a date column but a text column (varchar/nvarchar etc). You should store it in the database as a date, not a string.

If you *have* to store it as a string for some reason, store it in a sortable format e.g. yyyy/MM/dd.

As najmeddine shows, you *could* convert the column on every access, but I would try very hard not to do that. It will make the database do a *lot* more work - it won't be able to keep appropriate indexes etc. Whenever possible, store the data in a type appropriate to the data itself.

Comment: @dusoft: It doesn't really matter what separator you use, so long as it's in the right order of significance.

Comment: @Jon: It's easier to compare two hyphens than two slashes, because you don't have to deal with the angle. :-D

Answer (score 16):

Unsure what dbms you're using however I'd do it this way in Microsoft SQL:

```
select      [date]
from        tbemp 
order by    cast([date] as datetime) asc
```

Answer (score 9):

this works for me:

`SELECT datefield
FROM myTable
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, datefield) ASC`

Answer (score 3):

Following answer may help you

perform your date ordering by your date identifier but use to_char() function in select clause and use some other identifier in select clause for date

e.g.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DISPDATE1,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DISPDATE,
SUM(APPLCOUNT) AS APPLIED,
SUM(CONFCOUNT) AS CONFIRMED
FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(ID) AS APPLCOUNT,
                   0 AS CONFCOUNT,
                   STUDENT.APPLIED_ON AS DISPDATE1
            FROM STUDENT
            WHERE STUDENT.ID = P_ID
            GROUP BY STUDENT.APPLIED_ON
        UNION
            SELECT 0 AS APPLCOUNT,
                   COUNT(ID) AS CONFCOUNT,
                   STUDENT.CONFIRMED_ON AS DISPDATE1
            FROM STUDENT
            WHERE STUDENT.ID = P_ID
            GROUP BY STUDENT.CONFIRMED_ON
    )
GROUP BY DISPDATE1
ORDER BY DISPDATE1;
```

Comment: to_char and can other to_date(created_at, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as DISPDATE .. thanks Brushan! Work fine.

Answer (score 3):

SELECT CONVERT(char(19), CAST(date AS datetime), 101) as [date]
FROM tbemp 
ORDER BY convert(datetime, date, 101) ASC

Answer (score 3):

Try using this this work for me

```
select *  from `table_name` ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(start_date,"%d-%m-%Y") ASC
```

where **start_date** is the field name

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to edit several events in descendant chonologic order, and I just made a :

```
select 
TO_CHAR(startdate,'YYYYMMDD') dateorder,
TO_CHAR(startdate,'DD/MM/YYYY') startdate,
...
from ...
...
order by dateorder desc
```

and it works for me.
But surely not adapted for every case...
Just hope it'll help someone !

Answer (score 1):

This may help you in mysql, php.

```
//your date in any format
$date = $this->input->post('txtCouponExpiry');

$day = (int)substr($date, 3, 2);
$month = (int)substr($date, 0, 2);
$year = (int)substr($date, 7, 4);

$unixTimestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $year, $day, $month);

// insert it into database
'date'->$unixTimestamp;

//query for selecting  order by date ASC or DESC
select * from table order_by date asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Order by Convert(datetime,@date) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work for your date format

`order by convert(date, your_column, 104) desc`

Answer (score 1):

Casting/Converting can result in out of range exceptions that unfortunately are not always as simple as excluding nulls.

A simple alternative method, which avoids the cast, is:

```
SELECT date
FROM table
ORDER BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date) ASC;
```