# Ordering a list of dates

Tags: php, android, date

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","*********","***********","loadtracker");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}  
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Date FROM pallettracker GROUP BY Date");
$DateList = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$ListOfMonths=array('Dec','Nov','Oct','Sep','Aug','Jul','Jun','May','Apr','Mar','Feb','Jan');$ListOfDays = array('31','30','29','28','27','26','25','24','23','22','21','20','19','18','17','16','15','14','13','12','11','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1');
foreach ($ListOfDays as $value) {
foreach ($ListOfMonths as $value2) {
$Yaer = array("'$value2' + '$value' + ',2013'");
foreach ($Yaer as $yaerdate) {
 foreach ($DateList as $Dates) {
     if ($yaerdate == $Dates)
     {
         echo $yaerdate;
         echo '/';
     }
 } 
 }
 } 
 }
 ?>
```

trying to order a array of dates foratted as Jan28,2013 and Decending. And then display then with a / in-between them. For an Android App

Comment: Best way to order dates is YYYYMMDD. You should use this format to sort them and use a simple method to convert it into your desired style.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your SQL query order them for you. This assuming that the column is of the Date format. If it is not check out this: [SQL ORDER BY date problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545888/sql-order-by-date-problem).

After ordering in the query, you just need to convert it to a time then format the date as desired. This might give you what you are looking for:

```
<?

$datetime = strtotime($row->createdate);
$mysqldate = date("m/d/y g:i A", $datetime);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Date FROM pallettracker GROUP BY Date");

foreach($result as $date){
    $datetime = strtotime($result);
    $date = date("M d, y", $datetime);
    echo $date . '/';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it, why you are using GROUP BY when you don't use a grouping function.
The better way here is DISTINCT

I would update your code in this way:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT `Date` FROM `pallettracker` ORDER BY `Date` DESC");
while($date = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
{
    echo date('',strtotime($date['Date'])).'<br />';
}
```

It is important that you "Date" col in mysql is in the format Date or Datetime