# Order by latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, EffectiveTo, 105) as EffectiveTo 
FROM 
   CSchedules 
WHERE 
   CId = 3278 
ORDER BY 
   EffectiveTo ASC
```

Dates

```
03-08-2014
03-09-2017
03-09-2017
03-09-2017
09-11-2014
14-12-2014
16-11-2014
16-11-2014
20-07-2014
20-12-2015
23-11-2014
24-08-2014
27-12-2015
27-12-2015
30-11-2014
31-08-2014
31-08-2014
31-08-2014
```

I need to order by date so that:

```
03-09-2017
```

is the first in the list. However it does not order properly. Basically the latest date first.

When ordered by DESC:

```
31-08-2014
31-08-2014
31-08-2014
30-11-2014
27-12-2015
27-12-2015
24-08-2014
23-11-2014
20-12-2015
20-07-2014
16-11-2014
16-11-2014
14-12-2014
09-11-2014
03-09-2017
03-09-2017
03-09-2017
03-08-2014
```

Comment: `Order by effectiveto desc` then. Also, are those dates stored as `varchar`? If yes, that's not a good thing, and you will need to convert to datetime before ordering.

Comment: How about changing `ASC` to `DESC`?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545888/sql-order-by-date-problem

Comment: You need to have the covert in the order by as well to define it as a Datetime - see my answer

Answer (score 3):

Your `EffectiveTo` column is of a text type, like `varchar` instead of `date` or `datetime`. This is a very bad design. What you can do to workaround this is:

```
SELECT 
   EffectiveTo 
FROM 
   CSchedules 
WHERE 
   CId = 3278 
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(DATE, EffectiveTo, 105) DESC
```

This way, you are parsing the text as a date with dd-mm-yyyy format (that's the 105 parameter), so you can sort it properly.

You may optionally want to do a convert also in the `SELECT` if you want to show something different to the text stored in the column.

Comment: Oh, your field is of a TEXT type instead of `datetime`... Let me edit it.

Comment: Try what I posted now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the covert in the order by as well to define it as a Datetime rather than text

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, EffectiveTo, 105) AS EffectiveTo 
FROM CSchedules 
WHERE CId = 3278 
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, EffectiveTo, 105) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just order it as descending.
At the last line put-

```
Order by convert(varchar,effectiveto,112) desc
```

Comment: @Andrew , if I order as yyyymmdd then it will be ordered properly. i didn't tell to change the output. Output will remain as 105

Comment: But you are converting `EffectiveTo`, a `varchar` field with "dd-mm-yyyy" format (105), to a `varchar` once again. That has no effect on the data. It should be converted to `date` or `datetime` with format 105.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to date and then order it. Right now its not working because its considering it as string and not date

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, EffectiveTo, 105) as EffectiveTo 
FROM 
 CSchedules 
WHERE 
 CId = 3278 
ORDER BY 
 order by convert(datetime, EffectiveTo, 105) DESC
```

Comment: 106 is "dd mon yyyy".

Comment: @Andrew Sorry should be 105