# Find latest date in groups of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given this list of values in SQL Server 2012:

```
Status  Date
------  -----------
1       2016-12-01
1       2016-11-02
1       2016-10-20  <-- THIS
2       2016-10-01
1       2016-09-21  <-- (*)
3       2016-08-15
```

(*) Don't need this one because there is a "status 2" row between the sequence

I need to get the latest date of the list, but if there is a group of same status first, I need to return the minimum date of them. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: what? That date isn't the MIN for the status = 1 or the entire list... can you elaborate? and what version of sql server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545888/sql-order-by-date-problem

Comment: please show your expected output and also tag the version of SQL you are using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL ORDER BY date problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545888/sql-order-by-date-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method doesn't use window functions at all:

```
select top 1 t.*
from t cross join
     (select top 1 t2.id from t t2 order by t2.date desc) tt
where t.date > ifnull((select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id <> tt.id), '2000-01-01')
order by t.date;
```

The subquery `tt` returns the `id` on the most recent row in the table.  The subquery in the `where` clause selects the maximum date in the table for any other id.  Then the comparison in the `where` selects all the most recent records.

With window functions, `lag()` might be the easiest:

```
select top 1 t.*
from (select t.*, lag(status) over (order by date) as prev_status
      from t
     ) t
where prev_status <> status or prev_status is null
order by date desc;
```

The `where` clause gets the rows where the status changes.  The `top 1` and `order by date` get the most recent time this has occurred.

Comment: I used the query with lag() and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
  select
        status,
        min(date)
    from table
    where status in 
    (select
        status
    from table
    group by 1
    having count(date) > 1)
    group by 1
```

Checking all the statuses that appear more than once with the one query, and then from these statuses selecting the minimum date.

Comment: This query returns the minimum date of all records (in my case the row that i marked with an (*)). I need to get the date from the third row.