# How to dynamically add content from Database to Div Elements?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, web

I recently decided to work on a Dynamic Web Application. I will be using HTML, CSS, JSP, MS SQL DB and Servlets (and maybe PHP) in my application. I have selected an Online ticket website as an inspiration for my own Application. Since I have worked only on Static websites so far, I have come across a very frustrating problem.

I will explain my problem with a News Website. Say, when a News Editor submits a News Article, how is the article added to the div element (I assume that it's a Div element)on the main news page? Also, this new News Article pushes the previous news to the bottom, and takes the top spot.

For my own project, I want to create a Web page in which the Admin inserts various details about the events(such as sports,music shows)and then these events are passed to the div tags on the other page. The most recent events are shown on the top, while the older ones are pushed down.

My basic understanding is that the data input by the admin is sent and stored in DB table. The data from this table is now fetched by the web page containing the div/article/section tags. After this I have no idea what happens.

Many apologies for not bring super clear and for not understanding this concept. I just can't wrap my head around it :/ I will really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'll suggest you to use PHP and not JSP...PHP is easier for beginner and you can find more solution to your problems.

Now, connect to the database, select the item in your event table and print them in your document:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM EVENTS_TABLE ORDER BY 'DATE' ASC"; // ASC means you're ordering from newest to oldest 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<div class='event'><h3>". $row["EVENTNAME"] . "</h3><h6>" . $row["EVENTGENRE"] . "</h6></div>"; // Obviously you have to use your COLUMN_NAMES
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Since this will create a structure like this:

```
<div class="event">
    ...
</div>
<div class="event">
    ...
</div>
<div class="event">
    ...
</div>
```

You'll just have to wrap the code above in a simple div tag like this:

```
<div class="event-wrapper">
    <?php
        ... // The code above
    ?>
</div>
```

Some useful links:

- [SQL ORDER BY date problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545888/sql-order-by-date-problem)
- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp